# Rewrite rule to prevent apache decoding url before reaching htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a htaccess rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) ../app$1/scripts/api/index.php?fn=$2&$3 [L]
```

This works fine in most cases, however, Apache decodes the url before it arrives at this rule, so a url like `beta/list/&cat=red%20%26%20blue`, is seen by htaccess as `beta/list/&cat=red & blue` so we get `cat='red'` and `blue=null` coming into `index.php` instead of `cat='red & blue'`.

I've read that the workaround for this issue is to use server variables like `%{REQUEST_URI}` `%{THE_REQUEST}` in the htaccess rule as these are not decoded before use, but it's difficult to implement. The question mark in the RewriteRule makes everything go crazy and I can't figure out how to escape it.

Can any experts out there help me fix the rule below to behave like the one above?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule . ../app%1/scripts/api/index.php?fn=%2&%3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the solution is to use the special server-variable called `THE_REQUEST`.

From [mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> **THE_REQUEST**
>
> The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g.,
>   "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"). This does not include any additional
>   headers sent by the browser. **This value has not been unescaped
>   (decoded)**, unlike most other variables below.

Here is how your rule should look like

```
# don't touch urls ending by index.php
RewriteRule index\.php$ - [L]

# user request matching /xxx/xxx/xxx (with optional query string)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/\?]+)/([^/\?]+)/([^\?]+)(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ../app%1/scripts/api/index.php?fn=%2&%3 [L,QSA]
```

Please note that you shouldn't be using relative path for internal rewrite, which could lead to confusion. Instead, define a `RewriteBase`, use an absolute path or start from the domain root with a `/`.

## UPDATE

Since you can have encoded forward slashes in your url, you need to set `AllowEncodedSlashes` to `NoDecode` (or `On` but it's unsafe). Note also that, due to a bug, you must put this directive **inside** a virtual host context, even if the *server config* context is said to be OK (otherwise, it is simply ignored). By default, `AllowEncodedSlashes` is set to `Off`. So, Apache handles encoded slashes automatically by itself and refuses them, without passing the request to `mod_rewrite`. See the official documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes).

Comment: Thanks Justin. This looks promising but I'm getting a 404. Can you explain the reason for the first `RewriteRule`? What are the `\s` surrounding the regex for? Does this definitely pass through query strings in the original request?

Comment: I just added explanations in the code. The first rule prevents an internal rewrite loop, due to the second rule. The second rule matches an url format you asked for in your question. This does **not** include query string (but I can modify if you want it to be included). Also, `\s` are spaces.

Comment: I've tweaked your answer to include the query string to work in the example in the question. I've marked it as the accepted answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, the thing is, it won't work as expected by simply adding the `QSA` flag because the condition does not expect a query string. If a query string exists, the condition won't match. So you need to adapt the condition too. See the code up-to-date in my answer

Comment: Okay thanks. New issue now is with encoded forward slashes `%2F` and question marks `%3F` in the query string breaking the new rewriterule. Damn this is hard!

Comment: Something like this: `beta/list/&note=red%2Fblue%3F` is returning a 404 because the `%2F` is decoded somewhere to a slash and `%3F` is to a question mark.

Comment: OK, solved. See my edited answer (`UPDATE` section at the bottom)

Comment: Ok thanks Justin. I'm a bit nervous changing the config for my entire live domain but I'll investigate and see how it goes. Cheers

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, yes, it is always better to make sure the change is safe before applying it. If you look at the link I attached, the following is said: `If encoded slashes are needed in path info, use of NoDecode is strongly recommended as a security measure. Allowing slashes to be decoded could potentially allow unsafe paths.` So, if that makes you feel more comfortable, `NoDecode` is said to be safe by Apache